# c# set timeout for multipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync()

Tags: c#, async-await, settimeout, multipart

I'm using C# .net core to read upload data from multipart post user sending multiple files.
How can I prevent use waiting infinite after read last file in

```
try
{
  var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(1000);
  section = await multipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw;
}
```

Altough I've set cancelationToken for 1 second but it goes infinite, and won't go to 
next line if I will send another request.

```
public static async Task<HttpRequest> FromHttpContextAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            bool multipart = false;
            HttpRequest retVal = new HttpRequest(httpContext);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();         
            var sr = new StreamReader(httpContext.Stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            {
                var line1 = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                sb.AppendLine(line1);
                var Line1Parts = (line1).Split(' ');
                retVal.Methode = Line1Parts[0].ToLower();
                retVal.RawUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(Line1Parts[1]).Replace("&amp;", "&");
                var urlPart = retVal.RawUrl.Split('?');
                retVal.Url = urlPart[0];
                if (urlPart.Length > 1)
                {
                    foreach (var part in urlPart[1].Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        var tmp = part.Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        try
                        {
                            retVal.QueryStrings.Add(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            string line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
            sb.AppendLine(line);
            int contentLength = 0;
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                var tmp = line.Split(':');
                var key = tmp[0].Trim().ToLower();
                retVal.Header.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(tmp[0], tmp[1]));

                switch (key)
                {

                    case "cookie":
                        {

                            foreach (var part in tmp[1].Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                            {
                                var pares = part.Split('=');
                                if (pares.Length == 2)
                                {
                                    retVal.Cookies.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pares[0], pares[1]));
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "content-length":
                        {
                            contentLength = int.Parse(tmp[1]);
                            break;
                        }
                }
                line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
if (sb.ToString().Contains("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"))
{
  string boundary = FindBoundary(sb.ToString());
  MultipartReader multipartReader = new MultipartReader(boundary, httpContext.Stream);
  var section = await multipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
  while (section != null)
  {
    // process each image
    const int chunkSize = 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    var bytesRead = 0;
    var fileName = GetFileName(section.ContentDisposition);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      do
      {
        try
        {
          bytesRead = await section.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Console.Write(ex);
        }

        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      } while (bytesRead > 0);
      retVal.Files.Add(new Tuple<string, string, byte[]>("", fileName, stream.ToArray()));
    }

    try
    {
      var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
      cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(1000);
      section = await multipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw;
    }


  }
  foreach (var file in retVal.Files)
  {
    File.WriteAllBytes("d:\\" + file.Item2, file.Item3);
  }
}
```

HttpContext is inline class of this project and this is the source of HttpContext :

```
public class HttpContext
    {
        public HttpRequest Request { get; private set; }
        public HttpResponse Response { get; private set; }
        public Stream Stream { private set; get; }
        private HttpContext(Stream networkStream)
        {
            Stream = networkStream;
        }

        public async static Task<HttpContext> FromHttpContextAsync(Stream networkStream)
        {
            var retVal = new HttpContext(networkStream);
            retVal.Request = await HttpRequest.FromHttpContextAsync(retVal);
            retVal.Response = HttpResponse.FromHttpContext(retVal);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is the above code called? You also have not included the encapsulating method signature. Described symptoms sound like a deadlock, so suggest checking for deadlock first.

Comment: @Nkosi well I read data from stream until I reach to \r\n\r\n, which read all header, and from string exported from that, extract boundary, and pass stream and boundary for reading sections. what's the problem when want to read last section but there is no section

Answer (score 0):

While the lack of details and context makes trying to reproduce this issue really hard, I suspect the problem here is due to the fact NetworkStreams (used, under the covers, by your MultipartReader instance) do not yet fully support CancellationTokens. In fact, almost every Socket-related operation on .NET Core just checks for the eventually passed CancellationToken upfront - which is useless, in my opinion.

The good news is that the .NET Core team is actively working on this and I believe the issue will be completely solved in .NET Core 3.0:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24430

As a temporary ugly workaround, you can change your code to wait for both a fabricated delay task and your call to ReadNextSectionAsync(), assuming you don't want to re-used that stalled socket / NetworkStream after that:

```
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
var readNextSectionTask = multipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

if (await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, readNextSectionTask).ConfigureAwait(false) == timeoutTask)
{
    // TODO: Handle the timeout
}
else
{
    section = await readNextSectionTask;
}
```

Additionally, the fact you are not configuring your awaitable may act as a possible deadlock source (it is unclear to me whether you are running this code on ASP.NET Core itself or on some other synchronization context provider). To exclude this possibility, I would suggest to call ConfigureAwait(false) right after your await calls, as you can see on my previous code block.

Comment: @erfancobisi I've solved the problem by a component from mono old source: http://www.mono-project.com jgauffin/Griffin.WebServer